# Help VPN novice browse VPN

Tags: vpn

I need to connect to a network which has 2 entry points. I was provided the VPN entry point addresses, a username, password and a machine name to connect to. I am on a vista machine and so I followed the instructions on this page http://www.onecomputerguy.com/networking/vista_vpn_client.htm to arrive at a connection to one of the VPN entry points.

Now what I would like to do next is log on to the machine to browse and use software installed on the remote machine. How do I accomplish this using the VPN connection? I tried using remote desktop earlier but that did not work for some odd reason and I do not know any other way of connecting to a remote development machine except through Remote Desktop connection.

Any Idea what I may have wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Remote Desktop is the solution, but you need to use the IP address of the server machine to which you want to connect.

The VPN just adds a network to your machine, which looks to Vista exactly like an extra network card. Once you're connected to this network thru the VPN, which is the same as enabling a network card, you may then use IP addresses for computers that are found on this network.